# Couldn't load (find) j2v8_android_x86 library

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, apk, j2v8

I have a gradle project that uses [`j2v8_android 2.2.1`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eclipsesource.j2v8/j2v8_android/2.2.1) library (which provides Java bindings for V8 JS engine - android port). Unfortunately, after executing the project (build succeeds without issues), I get an exception related to missing `j2v8_android_x86` library file. The issues occurs when trying to create `V8` runtime:

```
V8 runtime = V8.createV8Runtime();
```

The exception itself is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: J2V8 native library not loaded.
        at com.eclipsesource.v8.V8.checkNativeLibraryLoaded(V8.java:86)
        at com.eclipsesource.v8.V8.createV8Runtime(V8.java:74)
        at com.eclipsesource.v8.V8.createV8Runtime(V8.java:63)
        (...)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load J2V8 library. Reasons:
Couldn't load j2v8_android_x86 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.androidscripting.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.androidscripting.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null
        at com.eclipsesource.v8.LibraryLoader.loadLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:71)
        at com.eclipsesource.v8.V8.load(V8.java:49)
        at com.eclipsesource.v8.V8.createV8Runtime(V8.java:72)
        ... 17 more
```

When I investigate the `apk` I see two library files at the root of the `apk` (`libj2v8_android_armv7l.so` and **`libj2v8_android_x86.so`**). If I understand it correctly, the names and location of those files is correct and they should be resolved.

The application is compiled and packaged by `Gradle 2.2.1` (on `Oracle JVM 1.8.0_45`) with `Android SDK 19` compatibility (with language level support `1.7`) and executed on `Hudl2` running `Android 4.4.2`.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but have you tried compiling under Java 7?

Comment: @DeadChex just tried with Oracle's `jdk 1.7.0_75` - same issue :(

Comment: Do you run it on a real device or on the emulator? j2v8_android_x86 is obviously a desktop thing, the device would use something that ends with `arm`.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 as mentioned I run it on `Hudl2` with `Android 4.4.2`. `j2v8_android_x86` is an android specific port of `j2v8` specific to devices running under `x86` architecture (some modern devices use intel chipset instead of arm and will often execute `x86` instruction set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After speaking to my colleges we found a solution. The path class loader does not actually look under the root of the `apk` - instead it looks in `libs/[ARCHITECTURE]`. Moving the `libj2v8_android_x86.so` file to `libs/x86` and repackaging did solve the problem.

I suppose the maven module may have been packaged for an older version and thus did not copy them into the correct directory on build - or may simply be misconfigured.