# build J2V8 with android sdk/ant. Exception: J2V8 Native library not loaded

Tags: java, android, ant, j2v8

I build my application with android sdk/ant (in ubuntu terminal). J2V8 is in the dependencies and it is built. When I try to run my application and I try to create a V8 runtime I get this: Exception: J2V8 Native library not loaded. My question is: how can I build it or include it in my application correctly?

Comment: I found the right answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892485/couldnt-load-find-j2v8-android-x86-library